# Sending out direct marketing an address at a time

Tags: phpmailer

I wasn't sure where to ask this and my knowledge of this kind of application is limited.

If I was to build a PHP Web app that sends out a pregenerated email using phpmailer or swift using SMTP with a pdf attached using mail server (1and1) likely to ban me? Do I need an opt out service if I only allow one message to be sent? There would be no follow up emails.

Basically the client would locate an email address he believes may benefit from his service (from other websites) enter their details (a database would keep track of recipients) and then click send fo send the email. He may end up sending up to 100 emails a day with a few minutes between sends.

Is this acceptable to implement?

Comment: "the client would locate an email address he believes may benefit from his service". Pretty sure signing up other people to your mailing list without their consent is illegal in a lot of countries. If it's not, it's certainly a great way to really annoy your customers.

Comment: It's not really a mailing list if you read the question, technically it's no different from sending out individual emails.  The only automation is creating an email body which he can tailor and attaching a pdf without having to locate it each time.  Read the whole thread next time.

Comment: you're still sending unsolicited marketing emails to people without their consent in a deliberate and organised fashion, having obtained their address from somewhere else again without their consent. It's a deliberate, repetitive process. The intent to harvest email addresses and end unsolicited generic marketing material on a large scale is still there, automated or not. Same would apply to material delivered by post.

Comment: If you're not planning to send follow-up emails, why are you keeping a database of recipients? In the UK that would be in breach of the Data Protection Act. You can't keep records of user data if you have no defined purpose for it, and you don't have consent. You'd have to destroy the list as soon as you finished sending the emails. What you're proposing to provide is basically a halfway house to a full spam operation, just without the last bit of automation.

Comment: The 'records' are kept on the database to ensure only one email could be sent per email address and also used to see how many are sent out daily etc.  The email address are in the public domain (from newspaper ads, google adverts etc) - that's the somewhere.  I wouldn't call it a halfway house, it has been built, performs well with no issues from clients (they receive around 20% of their jobs from it) and I was paid well for my services.

Comment: "The email address are in the public domain". I have an email address which can be found publicly. It's published to allow people to contact me for genuine business reasons. Publishing it in that context doesn't give you the right to harvest it, store it in _your_ database without asking and then send generic marketing information to it. Whether it works technically is irrelevant to whether it's legal or not. IANAL but certainly in the UK and EU this sort of approach would be regarded as pretty dodgy.

Comment: So you wouldn't mind being contacted for business reasons, such as working together on a project? Sounds like that's what my client achieves daily.  Does dodgy constitute illegal?  I did mention that it's a grey area from what was my perspective at the time, you would have seen that if you read the entire thread rather than jumping in and labeling it instantly as a spam bot.

Comment: I have read the entire thread, thankyou. It's just my opinion, you are welcome to disagree and do your own thing. I just thought I'd mention it as a warning. I said "dodgy" because I'm not a lawyer and can't say whether it's definitely illegal, plus I don't know where you're operating. But if I was you I'd want to ask one whether it was legit before continuing. That's all.

Comment: And I wouldn't mind being contacted about something genuine, but the way you've described it sounds like the client just picks out email addresses from the net, and fires off 100 emails a day. You said yourself the email and attachment are "pre-generated". To me that sounds closer to spam than carefully choosing potential business partners and making a personalised pitch. The email addresses chosen may not be entirely random but it's not far off.

Comment: Comments are duly noted, sorry to go off on one. I may look further into the legality when I get a chance. So far so god though, thanks for taking the time to comment.

Answer (score 2):

No. You need permission to send the first message - even sending an unsolicited message asking permission is enough to fall foul of legal issues and incur heavy fines - FlyBe found this out just recently and were [fined £70,000](http://www.travelmole.com/news_feature.php?news_id=2026516&region=2&cat=7).

What you're describing - harvesting emails from web sites, and sending them unsolicited marketing emails - has a more common name: **spamming**, and it's illegal.

Comment: Thanks for the info, sorry to sound lost.  Are you saying that contacting someone e.g. a builder and offer painting services in case they need a painter one day is illegal? Not to cause a full blown discussion and I'm thankful for the link and info but flybe emailed people who opted out which is understandable with regards to the fine. It's just what I've seen other businesses do in a B2b sense, he normal sends them out with Outlook I just figured this system may save a little time. If it is the case I'll opt not to build it.

Comment: It's really the automation of it that's frowned upon, just because it's so universally abused. The problem is that it's a very fine line between an individual emailing a bunch of people manually, and running a service to do the same. If you act as a third party in between, you're also exposing yourself to the requirements of being a data processor and all that that implies. Under the GDPR next year (and the likely collapse of Privacy Shield) it's only going to get harder.

Comment: Hmmm once again thanks for the info. It was just going to be a secure Web form where he enters details manually and it pins the pdf to it on the way out of the server. It would just save time locating the pdf and changing the email body in outlook e.g name of the business. I'll Google around about the legality of it as I don't want either of us in trouble. Would what I've describe be classed as automation? Thanks so much for you time on this.

Comment: I think a disclaimer at the bottom should cover our necks regarding privacy policy, where the address has come from and info regarding no future correspondence without a reply? If anyone else has any further information that would be great.